# Alternative phrase for "to linger on (an issue)"

Tags: phrases, synonyms

I want lay out several arguments about the same issue. I am looking for an alternative phrase for "to linger on (an issue)", to use it in a context similar to this, in order to introduce my second/another argument: "To linger on this issue / to continue on this point, there is also a potential problem with..."

To linger feels as if if has a negative connation (implying that I am boring the reader with my arguments). I am looking for a phrase which does NOT have this connation.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: In your example sentences, dropping the introductory phrases will do: "There is also a potential problem with ...".

Comment: @Lawrence You are right, but my example is more to illustrate what I am looking for rather than that it is an example for which it is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Consider, ***dwell (up)on** [something]*

> dwell (up)on someone or something
>
> to remain on the [important] subject of someone or something for a long time. (Upon is formal and less commonly used than on.) *I can't dwell upon this subject anymore*. *There is no need to dwell on Sarah further*.[FOD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dwell+on)
>
> *I would like to dwell upon this issue more.* [Kabbalah in Italy](https://books.google.fr/books?id=IYKBAcNXCe8C&pg=PA172&dq=%22to+dwell+upon+this+issue%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjykdKJrJ_LAhVJWxoKHSXABZcQ6AEIRzAG#v=onepage&q=%22to%20dwell%20upon%20this%20issue%22&f=false)

Comment: Thank you, upvoted. I do however feel that dwell on in a way has the same connotation with it as "linger on", namely that of being overly repetitive/boring.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to [***mull over***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/mull+over),

> Ponder, think about

[The Free Dictionary]

**Usage**:

> If you ***mull it over***, there is also a potential problem with...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps 'consider', as in "considering this issue further..." or "to consider this issue further...".

> consider (verb):
>   think carefully about (something), typically before making a decision.

Comment: Consider is the word.  I have never heard dwell used as such in any meeting I've ever attended.  Perhaps my crowd are dolts.  I don't know.  I've also heard "... now let's think about that".